# Twilio Flex - Send Call To IVR After Reject

Tags: twilio, twilio-flex

Using [this plugin](https://github.com/bruno222/twilio-flex-plugin-transfer-to-ivr) as a reference, I have Flex configured to be able to send a call to a Twilio Studio IVR, after an agent has accepted a call.

I'd like to be able to send an incoming call back to Studio when an agent rejects a call (i.e. as soon as they click the reject button). I'm trying to do this by adding a listener to the plugin's `init` method:

```js
flex.Actions.addListener("afterRejectTask", async (payload, abortFunction) => {
    let url: string = payload.task.attributes.transferToIvrUrl;
    let menu: string = 'hangup';
    await request(url, { CallSid: payload.sid, menu });
});
```

See [here](https://github.com/bruno222/twilio-flex-plugin-transfer-to-ivr/blob/main/src/TwilioFlexTransferToIvrPlugin.tsx) for the full context -- I'm pretty much using that exact code, with the addition of this listener.

I'm getting this error message, and the call is not transferred anywhere.

```
twilio-flex.unbundled-react.min.js:1574 Error on afterRejectTask: SyntaxError: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0
```

Here's additional context from the console, if that's helpful:

[image: additional context from the console]

Additional info:

The url being requested is a Twilio function, which successfully  returns a response like this:

```xml
<Response>
  <Enqueue workflowSid="WWcc1a650e4175089538d754a6c2e15a98">
    <Task>{"transferToIvrUrl": "https://my-twilio-function-service.twil.io/studio-flex-transfer-helper"}</Task>
  </Enqueue>
</Response>
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: That error mean that the response to the `request` did not contain JSON, but was attempted to be parsed as such. What is the URL you are passing there and what does it respond with? Can you tell, in the network tab, whether the request was a success or otherwise?

Comment: @philnash Thanks for the suggestion. Updated my question with additional info. That the response is returning XML that the plugin is trying to parse as JSON would be the issue.

That does give me more to go on, but I'm not sure how to modify my listener to avoid that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, ok, so looking at that plugin I found [the example Twilio Function that works with it](https://github.com/bruno222/twilio-flex-plugin-transfer-to-ivr/blob/main/.docs/function-send-to-flex-and-back-to-studio.js). From what I can tell, this function is intended to be used in two places, either in Studio to transfer the call to Flex (though I'm not sure it's needed for that) or from Flex to transfer the call back to Studio. The thing that triggers the different response is whether you pass an argument called `transferToIVRMenu` with the request.

Your current request is not passing that argument, you currently have:

```js
    await request(url, { CallSid: payload.sid, menu });
```

which looks similar to the original plugin's request:

```js
    await request(transferToIvrUrl, { CallSid: call_sid, transferToIVRMenu });
```

The difference is in the second property in the object. When you just pass the name of the variable in an object, it expands to call the property the same name as the variable and set the value to the value within the variable. So the original request expands out to:

```js
    await request(transferToIvrUrl, { CallSid: call_sid, transferToIVRMenu: transferToIVRMenu });
```

but your request only expands to:

```js
    await request(url, { CallSid: payload.sid, menu: menu });
```

So you are passing a parameter called `menu` not `transferToIVRMenu` and that triggers the Function on the back end to return TwiML and not to update the call.

To fix this, you can update your plugin code to send the `transferToIVRMenu` parameter, like:

```js
flex.Actions.addListener("afterRejectTask", async (payload, abortFunction) => {
    let url: string = payload.task.attributes.transferToIvrUrl;
    let menu: string = 'hangup';
    await request(url, { CallSid: payload.sid, transferToIVRMenu: menu });
});
```

Comment: That did get be past that particular issue. It seems that I needed a few more updates for this plugin to do what I wanted it to do, however. 

The original plugin author provided additional guidance here: https://github.com/bruno222/twilio-flex-plugin-transfer-to-ivr/issues/2

Thanks -- I'm impressed with the responsiveness of Twilio employees!

Comment: Glad you’re progressing! We are happy to help you succeed 